# problem while displaying UIAlertview with textfield and buttons

Tags: iphone

I need to place 3 buttons and one textfield  in UIAlertview. I wrote code like this.

```
UIAlertView *share = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Refresh" message:nil   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", @"Contacts", nil];
 share.tag = 2;
 [share setDelegate:self];
 [share setTitle:@"Enter Name"];
 [share setMessage:@" "];

 nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
 [nameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
 [nameField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypePhonePad];
 [share addSubview:nameField];
 [share show];
 [share release];
 [nameField release];
```

But it displays [like this](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/37d341b982.jpg).

If i place 2 buttons it displays fine.

when ever i add new button it add in next row as show above link.

But I need to display all the three buttons in a single column.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make room for the UITextField by adding a necessary number of @"\n" to your message string.

Add a couple of them (like:  @"Are you want to Refresh Data\n\n") and see what happens.

I have tried this method in the past and It worked but I have some problems when rotating the device while the alert is being shown. The layout becomes a mess.

You can also try subclassing UIAlertView like in [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/alert-view-with-prompt.html)

**EDIT:**

I have just tried and realized that UIAlertView has a max height this is why this is not working(also the reason why it works with 2 buttons and not with 3 or more).

You cannot arrange buttons of UIAlertView, not at least with public APIs, If you are interested in undocumented APIs look at Erica Sadun's book, there is a lot of stuff there regarding  UIAlertView customization. But before that, Why do you need these 2 buttons: "OK" and "Done"? Don't they have the same meaning? (at least from the user point of view)

My point is, if its too much work for 3 buttons, then rethink your title/message and maybe it can be done with only 2.

Hope it helps

Comment: I am trying by placing message nil but no change. I need buttons in  horizontally in a single column,Not in a vertical... Can u pls edit u r answer.

Comment: Is there any other ways similar to my requirement